# Sampling discrete distributions given their entropy

Tags: distributions, simulation, random-generation, discrete-data, entropy

Can we (uniformly) generate a discrete random variable over 
$n$ possible outcomes given its entropy? I am interested in non-parametric methods, that do not require the random variable to follow a specific distribution.

This problem is equivalent to finding $\{x_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ with:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$$
and:
$$-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \, \text{log}_2(x_i) = \text{given entropy}$$

Finding one discrete distribution with a given entropy is not difficult (using a greedy algorithm) but uniformly sampling one from all potential distributions seems much harder.

Comment: Can you tell us something about the context in which this arises ...

Comment: Yes, the final goal is to analyze multivariate data sets of discrete data, and find an approximate model to generate them given a few parameters. Here, the problem consists of generating one discrete distribution (one column) given a few parameters (entropy, number of values, _etc._).

Comment: Because in general the entropy determines the random variable only when $n\le 2,$ this question doesn't have any definite answer.  The references to "all potential distributions" and "uniformly sample" suggest you might have in mind some probability measure defined on a set of possible distributions, but that's unclear and its connection with entropy is obscure.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of limited value, but who knows. A bit depends on what you mean by *uniformly* in this case. With a target entropy $H$:

1. Generate $X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}$, all independently from $U(0, 1)$.
2. Sort them to get the order statistics $X_{(1)}, \dots, X_{(n-1)}$, and define $X_{(0)} := 0$ and $X_{(n)} := 1$.
3. For $k = 1, ..., n$ set $p_k(s) := X^s_{(k)} - X^s_{(k-1)}$. Note that $p_1(s) + \cdots + p_n(s) = 1$.
4. Select $s$, if possible, so that $-p_1(s)\log_2 p_1(s) - \cdots - p_n(s)\log_2 p_n(s) = H$ and return $p_1(s), \dots, p_n(s)$; otherwise, repeat at Step 1.

A few experiments show this can work pretty well as long as the target entropy is in the range appropriate for $n$ probabilities.