# How to sample distributions far from uniform?

Tags: sampling, entropy

I need to obtain an isotropic sample of discrete distributions over $d$ outcomes which are far from uniform in some measure.

For instance, using [linear entropy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)#Linear_entropy) as the complexity measure, we can isotropically sample from the simplex, reject points with $\sum_i p_i^2<c$. However, for $d=100$, this has almost 100% probability of rejection  unless $c\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}$ (as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533715/sampling-from-intersection-of-sphere-and-simplex)). Any tips?

**Motivation**: I have a cheap approximation which works well when input is close to uniform, need  to check if it's good for inputs far from uniform.

Comment: This sounds too general to answer.  As you know, some distributions that comport with your assumptions have efficient sampling method (Poisson, Negative Binomial, etc.). How, specifically, are your distributions given to you?  In what form?

Comment: It's a discrete distribution over $d$ outcomes. Given as $d$ positive reals adding up to 1. Two specific instances are [sampling with entropy constraint](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250196/sampling-discrete-distributions-given-their-entropy), [sampling with linear entropy constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533715/sampling-from-intersection-of-sphere-and-simplex)

Comment: One approach  could be to start with vector $(1,0,0,...,0)$ and perform random walk in the simplex until it's within $d$ of uniform in Euclidean distance. How do I ensure the resulting distribution is isotropic? Feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by an "isotropic sample" of an arbitrary discrete distribution?  Isotropy means there's some kind of metric, but nothing like that is inherent in this general setting.

Comment: I'm using isotropic measure for Euclidian space. IE, for a random discrete distribution $v$ viewed as a random vector in Euclidian space, density of $v/||v||$ is constant over its support

Comment: You lost me, because earlier you wrote "it's a discrete distribution over $d$ outcomes." What is the sense in which this is Euclidean vector with a *density* describing its distribution??

Comment: A sample of $k$ discrete distributions can be viewed as a sample of $k$ vectors in $R^d$. We could take a sampler of vectors and ask whether it's isotropic (every direction which may eventually be encountered by generating a large enough sample, must be equally likely)

Comment: For a finite sample size isotropy would be impossible.  Indeed, since all these vectors lie in a single quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ the distribution couldn't possibly be isotropic in the usual sense.  You will need to show more explicitly how you are conceiving of this situation.

Comment: Isotropic over the support of the measure. Simple way to do this is sampling from isotropic measure and rejecting samples outside of the quadrant. Rejection sampling is too inefficient, so I need a faster approximate approach, probably MCMC based

Comment: We really need you to define what you mean by "isotropic."  I cannot find any way to apply the usual meaning of this word to your situation.

Comment: A measure over vectors in $R^{d}$ such density of $v/\|v\|$ is constant over its support. For instance, sampling vectors $v$ with standard Gaussian components, rejecting instances with negative components, then letting $u=v / \sum_i v_i$ would satisfy this for $u$

Comment: That's impossible in this circumstance due to the discreteness of the distribution.  Also, your attempt to define "isotropic" conflicts with its standard meaning as invariant under all rotations.

Comment: Curious if there's a more acceptable terminology to characterize the observed uniformity of u/||u|| for u in my previous comment. "Constant directional density over the support" perhaps?

Comment: It has to depend on the distribution.

Comment: I'm sampling from isotropic density, and rejecting instances outside of the positive orthant. Even though it's not technically "isotropic", it retains local similarity to original measure. I'm looking to make my sampler more efficient while retaining this "locally isotropic" nature of the generating density

Comment: It's hard to see how such a program could succeed, because this discrete distribution is singular with respect to your "isotropic density."

Comment: It's a continuous distribution over vectors. For $d=2$, this is equivalent to sampling from a quarter of a circle. Each vector is then mapped to a discrete distribution over 2 outcomes.

Comment: How does this mapping occur??

Comment: Suppose I sample vector (0.707,0.707). I normalize to make entries add up to 1, to get (0.5,0.5), and now treat this as a Bernoulli distribution with parameter p=0.5

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm completely lost.  You seem to be talking about a prior distribution over the space of discrete distributions with $n$ categories, but nothing you have written makes any sense to me in terms of sampling from a single discrete distribution.

Comment: I need to obtain a sample of discrete distributions. Since discrete distributions are isomorphic to vectors in Euclidean space, this is equivalent to obtaining a sample of vectors

Comment: Your language is ambiguous, but finally I understand: by "sample of discrete distributions" you *don't* mean you're sampling a *given* discrete distribution!  It would be far clearer just to state that you're trying to sample the simplex in $\mathbb{R}^d.$  As a general proposition there's little to say, but if you would provide some details about *what* distribution in the simplex you want to sample, then maybe you would get some useful answers.

Comment: I specified some details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533715/sampling-from-intersection-of-sphere-and-simplex) but this seems like a hard problem

Comment: Well, yes, because it is so completely general!  Or, perhaps, by "isotropically sample" would you mean the *uniform distribution*?  Because that intersection is a $d-2$-sphere, the problem doesn't sound at all difficult.

Comment: Intersection of simplex and a sphere of radius $R$ in $d$ dimensions is a collection of $d$ disconnected regions for most values of $R$, rejection sampling suffers from poor efficiency, so this makes the problem hard

Comment: Now that I have read the comment threads to the question you linked to, I see what your question is.